# Minimal esign example

Tags: docusignapi

I am learning how to use the DocuSign API by going through the C# quickstart and examples, specifically the [sign via email](https://github.com/docusign/code-examples-csharp/blob/master/launcher-csharp/eSignature/Controllers/Eg002SigningViaEmailController.cs) example. The example is nice, industrial strength  and feature complete. However, it includes a number of objects (e.g. User, Session, RequestItems) that are initialized in filters, injected through DI etc. Some of these items are still a mystery to me, e.g. how does the User.AccessToken or Session.AccountId get their values. So, it is difficult to figure out what values are generated by DocuSign, what is assigned locally, what is essential, what is useful, etc.

I am trying to get the most simple example working, with a minimal set of objects. Is it possible to have the example as a standalone Controller, with one action method and associated methods in one common class. This would greatly expedite comprehension.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case this is helpful, I created this newbie-friendly example to walk interested users through the basic eSignature workflow to send an envelope, and download its contents. It has exactly one controller and one view, no filters, no dependency injection, no services etc. It extracts the authorization and sending methods from eg002 and downloading methods from the API documentation.

https://github.com/ISM6225/DocusignStart

To use it, create the ASP.NET core QuickStart app from https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/quickstart/, populate the sender information and private key, then run the app.